# wordpress login blank screen

Tags: wp-admin, localhost, wp-load.php

i wanted to make an offline copy of my live website on my pc so i installed xamp and installed on it wordpress and exported the database and took a copy of files on fttp and after i have done eveything and i wanted to make open my live website to edit something 
it gives me a blank page when i open

```
 "www.sitename.com/wp-admin"
```

but when i open

```
"www.sitename.com/wp-login.php"
```

it open put when i insert username and password it also gives me blank page

i opened the wp-config and i found that dp host became **"localhost"** i think this is my problem but how can i get my dbhost back is there a way to find it

Comment: localhost is probably the correct setting, if the database is on the same server as the web server. Check the error logs on the web server for any errors. try setting WP_DEBUG to true in you wp_config.php file and check if you get any error output in the browser.

Comment: ok it gave me error Warning: Cannot modify header information

Comment: @sarah In wp-config.php file remove all spaces before "`<?php" and after "?>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem there was space in function.php

Answer (score -1):

Add this code to theme's functions.php file

```
add_action('init', 'clear_buffer_output');
function clear_buffer_output() {
        ob_start();
}
```

Comment: Please: NO. That could hide the problem; it is not a solution. And without an explanation, this isn’t even an answer.